# SQL - Find the object with the most appearances

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am a newbie to SQL working on an assignment to find the actor or actress with the most appearances. A diagram of the database I'm working with is here: 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/kj8qVgF.png]
Here was the query I was trying to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.name, count(n.name)
FROM cast_info c
INNER JOIN name n
ON (n.id = c.person_id)
INNER JOIN title t
ON (c.movie_id = t.id)
CROSS JOIN role_type r
WHERE (r.role = 'actor' OR r.role = 'actress')
GROUP BY n.name
```

This is intended to get a count of how many times different actors showed up, which I can then sort and select the top one. But it doesn't work. Something else I did was:

```
SELECT n.name, count(n.name) AS amount
FROM cast_info c
INNER JOIN name n
ON (n.id = c.person_id)
INNER JOIN title t
ON (c.movie_id = t.id)
LEFT JOIN role_type r
ON c.role_id = r.id
AND (r.role = 'actor' OR r.role = 'actress')
GROUP BY amount
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But that gives the error

```
aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (SELECT n.name, count(n.name) ...
```

Tips?

Comment: I didn't mention this in my answer, but the reason you're getting an error is because you can't group by an aggregate column. Amount is considered an aggregate because it counts something, and it gets the count from a group. It can't get a count from itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.name, count(n.name)
FROM cast_info c
INNER JOIN name n
ON n.id = c.person_id
INNER JOIN title t
ON c.movie_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN role_type r
ON c.role_id = r.id
AND (r.role = 'actor' OR r.role = 'actress')
GROUP BY n.name
```

Comment: I tried this and the query could not process even after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a stab at each of these questions for you, because this assignment is obviously causing you some trouble.

You can find everything you need in your cast_info table and your role_type table, unless you need to display the actors/actresses actual name.

I would start by selecting all rows that represent an actor or actress in a movie. This should be a unique combination, as a person can't be an actor in the same movie twice. Once you've done that, group by the persons id and get the count() of rows, which should effectively be the number of movies. I think the error you're getting is exactly for the reason it sounds, you can't use an aggregate column in your order by. A workaround for that would be to use this as a subquery, and use MAX() to get most appearances.

Try this:

```
SELECT c.personid, MAX(numMovies) AS mostApperances
FROM(SELECT c.personid, COUNT(*) AS numMovies
     FROM cast_info c
     JOIN role_type r ON r.id = c.role_id
     WHERE r.role = 'actor' OR r.role = 'actress'
     GROUP BY c.personid) t
```